# Ruby Tutorial and "uniqueness"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been following this tutorial, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#top, which I find great, but it mentions something about the uniqueness attribute which I don't get.
This is mu user file so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    #these attributes can be modified by the users
    attr_accessible :name, :email;

    #validation testing
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    #regular expression (there is an official one)
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    #and add it..
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

It says:

"    Using validates :uniqueness does not guarantee uniqueness.

Alice accidentally clicks on “Submit” twice, sending two requests in quick succession.
The following sequence occurs: request 1 creates a user in memory that passes validation, request 2 does the same, request 1’s user gets saved, request 2’s user gets saved.
Result: two user records with the exact same email address, despite the uniqueness validation."

I tried creating 2 users with the same email address using the console, (and the User.create method), and uniqueness seemed to work fine since only the first one got into sqlite3. So what could cause an error or uniqueness to fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the point the tutorial is trying to make is that the uniqueness validation is enforced by the application layer, not by the database. If you had a system that could handle multiple requests simultaneously, the :uniqueness validation suffers from what is known as a race condition.

The way uniqueness works is to (1) query the database for a matching record. If a matching record is not found, then validation passes and (2) the record is saved to the database. Between steps (1) and (2), it is theoretically possible, although unlikely, for another request to swoop in and add a matching record to the database.

The problem can be avoided by also enforcing uniqueness in the database. How to do that is dependent on the database you are using; Rails does not assist you in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two instances of RoR talking to the same SQL server, there could be the following scenario:

```
process A reads, no email like 'foo@bar'
process B reads, no email like 'Foo@BAR'
process A writes new User with 'foo@bar'
process B writes new User with 'Foo@BAR'
```

Ruby doesn't support more than one `Thread` at a time, therefore you need two separate RoR processes.

This problem can be solved if you write your uniqueness enforcement in SQL, or use `DataMapper` instead of `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: C-Ruby (MRI and YARV) does not use native threads but green threads. Alternative implementations like JRuby or Rubinius use native threads. However both types can observe the race condition in a single process.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint fails when two parallel processes try to save a conflicting object

```
    Process 1                   Process 2

1.  Create Object in Memory
2.                              Create Object in Memory
3.                              Check DB -> valid
4.  Check DB -> valid
```

Now both processes think they have validated their uniqueness constraint and continue to save the object.

```
5.  save
6.                              save
```

The issue now is, that both processes check the uniqueness before saving their objects. So both processes see that there is no conflict at the time of checking. The conflict only starts to exists after step 5. The issue now is, that it is not checked during step 6 and process 6 thus saves an invalid object that does not follow the unique constraint.

To mitigate that, you can create a unique index on your database. That will definitely ensure that you can't insert invalid data into your db as the constraint is checked by the database in an *atomic* way, so that the race condition does not occur anymore.

Now you could rely only on that unique index. However you will notice that you will not get nice error messages if an error occurs there.  So in practice you should use both. So for most of the cases you can rely on the nicely integrated unique constraint of rails. For the rare cases of race conditions, you can then rely on the unique index to make sure your data is save 100% of the time.